# Python: Problem with assigning Pearson's r, value to the variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I have quite surprising behavior of the result of calculating Pearson's r. I can calculate that and get the value:

```
 print (scipy.stats.pearsonr(dff['Y'], dff['X']))   #result (0.8288.., 0.0)
```

but if I try to do anything with that like even:

```
r=scipy.stats.pearsonr(dff['Y'], dff['X'])



print (r)   #result (nan, nan)
```

I get empty results. That is only the case calculating pearsonr, spearmanr and kendalltau works correctly

Comment: It will easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @warrenWeckesser that of course is good idea. Only in that case seems that problem is data related. If I will do something like that:   
import pandas as pd   
import scipy.stats   
inp = [{'Y':10, 'X':100}, {'Y':14,'X':110}, {'Y':12,'X':120}]   
dff = pd.DataFrame(inp)   
print (scipy.stats.pearsonr(dff['Y'], dff['X']))   
r=scipy.stats.pearsonr(dff['Y'], dff['X'])   
print (r)   
it works as expected.

Comment: Please don't put code in the comments.  [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66443839/edit) your question instead. Does your dataframe contains `NaN`s (or infinity)?  You might try to leave them out.

Comment: quite surprisingly, the problem disappeared and for the last few days it doesn't occur anymore... thank you for all your comments. If I will figure out what was the reason for that I will let you know.